# MicroMeter LongTaskTimer how to clear sample when method failed

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

I use Micrometer LongTaskTimer to record the time cost when something creates success;
when nothing creates success, the metrics have values.

```java
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MetricConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @Bean(name = "creationTimer")
    LongTaskTimer creationTimer() {
        //TODO only apply to event,not for api
        return LongTaskTimer.builder("creationTimer")
                .description("timer for pipeline create process")
                .publishPercentileHistogram()
                .publishPercentiles(0)
                .register(meterRegistry);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CreationWorker {

    private LongTaskTimer.Sample createTimerSample;

    private LongTaskTimer createTimer;

    public CreationWorker(LongTaskTimer createTimer) {
        this.createTimer = createTimer;
    }

    public boolean execute() {    
        if(dbStatus = 'toCreate')
            return doCreate();
        if(dbStatus = 'creating')
            return checkCreated();
 
    }

    public boolean doCreate() {
        createTimerSample = createTimer.start();
        //then do along async create task
        //update dbStatus='creating'
    }

    public boolean checkCreated() {
        Status status = ...; //get async task status
        if (status.equals("success"))) {
            createTimerSample.stop();
            return true
        }
        // I think need to clear the longTaskTimer
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my local test env, the async task will never "success", but creationTimer have values,
I think it needs to clear longTaskTimer when failed. But I don't know how to clear。

Answer (score 1):

I recommend stopping the sample in the failure scenario as well but register a tag that will tell you about the outcome (success/failure). With this, you can track the success events, the failure events, and both.

This is what Micrometer itself does if you use `@Timed`: [see here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/c44f076197ed3875892e6219daaf61540d14ccb4/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java#L216)